# UIScrollView Not working properly in IOS6

Tags: uiscrollview, ios6, uitabbar

I'm using a simple UIScrollview in a One of my TabBarViews. I want this to work with autolayout so I did some searching I found out the the ViewDidappear method works with autolayot.
The scroller works fine with the viewdidAppear instead of viewDidLoad, but when i switch to another tab without scrolling back to the top it does not release or something.
When I go back to the scrollview tab the scroller is not able to go all the way to the top? 
It starts where i left of and scrolls all the lenght from there.

http://tinypic.com/r/24dmys8/6
Start of scroll, when I contiune to scrolldown and switch tab.

http://tinypic.com/r/2e37vb9/6
When I come back from another tab the scroll starts at this point. I think Iit's some kind of release problem... But I can't work out what?!

Here is the code I've used:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];


[self.ScrollviewVT2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0,1440.0)];
[self.ScrollviewVT2 setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
   }
```